# Menu and Message Dialog QT/QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am creating a project with many qml files. I create 1 Menu and 1 MessageDialog. I want when clicking on the menuItem Signout, the Question "OK" or "Cancel" window will appear. But when I click "Cancel" my main window is closed again. Here is my code:

```
Menu{
        id: menu
        y : profile.height + 40
        x : 890
        MenuItem
        {
            text: "Profile"
        }
        MenuItem
        {
            text: "Setting"
        }
        MenuItem
        {
            text: "Help"
            
        }
        MenuItem
        {
            text: "Sign out"
            onClicked: {
                messageDialog.open()
            }

        }

    }
    MessageDialog {
        id: messageDialog
        icon: StandardIcon.Question
        title: "Quit"
        text: "Do you want quit App now ???"
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel
        onAccepted: {this.close()}
        onRejected:  {console.log("Cancel")}
        Component.onCompleted: visible = false
    }
```

Comment: what does `main window is closed again` mean? especially _again_. and I guess you have to replace `this` with `messageDialog` in the `onAccepted` handler.

Comment: In the project I want when click  "Sign Out"  to show "Ok" and "Cancel" option. But when I click "Cancel", the main window doesn't work and close

Comment: I guess you provided incomplete code. Your `onRejected` handler has no code that can crash.  I guess you have to provide [mcve] and clarify your question, mainly the workflow

Comment: thank you, i think something went wrong when i use multiple qml files. If you don't mind, you can check out my project on github https://github.com/duongminhthong10/Library

Answer (score 0):

Try This: when you use `onRejected` didn't mean cancel. and I think you have a problem somewhere else, I test your code like here and it works:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

Window {
    id:root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: fileButton
        text: "button"

        onClicked: menu.open()

        Menu{
            id: menu
            y : fileButton.height
            MenuItem
            {
                text: "Profile"
            }
            MenuItem
            {
                text: "Setting"
            }
            MenuItem
            {
                text: "Help"

            }
            MenuItem
            {
                text: "Sign out"
                onClicked: {
                    messageDialog.open()
                }

            }

        }
    }


    MessageDialog {
        id: messageDialog
        icon: StandardIcon.Question
        title: "Quit"
        text: "Do you want quit App now ???"
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Yes | StandardButton.No
        onYes:  {root.close()}
        onNo:  {console.log("Cancel")}
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my project consists of many .qml files. I'm afraid I've encountered a problem while managing my files leading to an error. Can you help me? , This is the path to the project on github [link](https://github.com/duongminhthong10/Library) . Login section, you just need to click "Login". Thank you very much

Comment: I see your code, you have crashed on any Rejected signal , not in cancel sign out, If you close about the window you have that crash , I should read more and will tell your bug , It may take time.

Comment: Thank you for your help, looking forward to your reply

Comment: can you help me? I have tried many ways but still get this error.